# DNN 7 - SMTP Test in host settings work, but can't send emails in contact forms

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

All the sites on this DNN installation stopped sending emails yesterday.  When you try and test SMTP in host settings, it sends the test email without any issues.

At first I thought my IP might be blacklisted, but then surely the SMTP test would also fail?

Comment: Do you have more information? Log, Module name???

Comment: It's the free default Feedback module.  Have now rebuild my server also upgraded to Windows Server 2012.  Configured SMTP server in IIS6 console.  As before the SMTP test works, and we have slightly more success.  It will send email to whomever completes the feedback form and opts into getting a copy.  But not to the administrator.

Comment: You can find the latest logs here: http://goo.gl/Czn7uK

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Test SMTP setting in Host directly calls the send mail service in DNN's API.  But many other emails are queued up for dispatch for scalability.

Check to see if your "Messaging Dispatch" job in Host > Scheduler has been disabled.  If not, check the history by clicking the Log icon on the right-hand side of the schedule tasks list.  See if there are errors logged in there.

If all is good there, check your Logs in /Portals/_default/Logs for any issues related to messaging or SMTP.

Comment: All entries in "Messaging Dispatch" shows as Succeeded, no errors, but also "0" messages sent.  In the logs /Portals/_default/Logs there is no mention of SMTP or anything related to messaging. Thanks for the tips. The search continues for a solution.

Comment: Supervan,  if you are using gmail as your smtp, be aware they have made changes to how you can use it.  Be sure to create an application password for your DNN site.  To do this, go to your google account page, scroll down to the Sign In panel and click "App Passwords".  Create a custom app and name it "DNN Dev Site" or something.  Get the password and setup your DNN SMTP credentials as follows: SMTP Server and port: smtp.gmail.com:587,  SMTP Authentication: Basic, SMTP Enable SSL: True, SMTP Username: username@gmail.com, SMTP Password: [generated app password]

Comment: I'm Using the server's own SMTP.  Upgraded the server to 2012 now and configured SMTP.  It will now send emails only to the person completing the Feedback form and selects to get a copy. Not to the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking to see if you have defined a valid (usable) email address on your ADMIN account. DNN will "send" emails from whatever the Administrator is in the site settings, so check the email address on that user's profile, make sure that the email/domain is valid and the SMTP settings you are using are allowed to send from that domain.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, have checked and it's a regular Google Apps account.  It's been able to send emails in the past, and I got it to work on one of my sites.  But only once.  Now it stopped again.  No errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developed contact-form dynamic module in your DesktopModules folder then you have to call below DNN SendMail method in your submit button click event.

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail(FromEmailAddress, ToEmailAddress, CCEmailAddress, BCCEmailAddress,
                                                    DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailPriority.Normal,
                                                    EmailSubject,
                                                    DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailFormat.Html, 
                                                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 
                                                    EmailBodyMessage, "", "", "", "", "");
```